# Vim: No lines in buffer

Tags: vim

I recently got started using Vim but I've started to get this whenever I try to open something with vim:

"[No Name]" --No lines in buffer--

Is there a way to get rid of this? Or could someone explain what's going on?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/vim_use/V8IMril3Nqw) and [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14443/quit-vim-is-slow-usually-2-seconds-it-shows).

Comment: Do you have it customized (anything in your .vimrc?) or are you just working off straight vanilla vim?

Comment: Ah I think I figured it out. There was just a little typo in my vimrc.